# Convert domxpath to an array.

Tags: php

I am using Xpath in PHP . How do i convert domxpath to an array ? Also I dont want the output in a single line.

I have tried the following code:

```
    foreach($car_row as  $key=>$row){
       echo $key . ':' . $row->nodeValue . "<br/>"; 
    }
```

Comment: And what happened next.Any errors.Any doubts..?

Comment: no errors but m getting the output in a single line. i wan to divide the output into different rows. how do i do tat?